# delete data from sql using button

Tags: php, sql, html

Hello there i am having trouble joining the button whit the id, reason i need to join them together it's.
After button and id its one, on button click i can delete the row in theory any way.
Look that its my idea of button and id, that i can`t join them together.

```
echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\type=\button\">";
echo("<button onclick=\"location.href='google.com'\">delete user</button>");
echo $results['id'];
```

And i was thinking i can place this within the href and make it a delete button.
I steal need a idea how to place this inside the href

```
DELETE FROM MY TABLE
WHERE button='id';
```

I have look inside w3schools and other www pages but i cant fund anything that works.
Just to you can understand why my code its so bad its because i am not a developer its a lovely stressful hobby.

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML

```
echo("<button onclick=\"location.href="google.com?id=".$results['id']."\">use</button>");
```

and in your PHP

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

and your Query should be like this,

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id='$id';
```

Comment: it das not work it ghive me a sintax eror cause it haze to be place hear. echo("<button onclick=\"location.href="google.com?id=<?php echo $results['id'];?\">use</button>");

Comment: you can't put `<?php  ?>` inside `echo`, you must take some basic lessons first about PHP

Comment: answer updated but highly suggest don't mix PHP with HTML